# superscript and subscript the same character in an expression

Tags: r, plot, expression

In a plot I would like a title which should have:

the string "my title is" followed by  the caharecter alpha raised by `'` (i.e. alpha prime) with alpha also having the subscript G.

I tried:

```
expression(paste("my title is ",alpha^{"'"}[G],")"))
```

but the above code raises alpha to the power `'G` . How do I superscript the  `'` but subscript the `G` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either of the following would do the trick:

```
alpha[G]^"'"
{alpha^{"'"}}[G]
```

They are typeset slightly differently, so pick whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the syntax to the following works:

```
expression(paste("my title is ",alpha[G]^{"'"},")")))
```